# Conditional probability of a Joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X,Y)$ have joint density $f(x,y)=e^{-y}$ , for $0<x<y$, and $f(x,y)=0$ elsewhere.

What is  $f_{X\mid Y} (x,y)$ for $0<x<y$?

I think that the answer is $1/y$, however, I am having a hard time writing a clean proof. I know that when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, this conditional density should be equal to the marginal density of $X$, but can't seem to make things work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use definition of $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ as follows:

$$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)} = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(z,y)dz} = \frac{e^{-y}}{\int_{0}^{y}e^{-y}dz} = \frac{e^{-y}}{ye^{-y}} = \frac{1}{y}$$

This is true when $0 \leq x \leq y$, else $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

We use the definitions of conditional probability density, and marginal density to obtain:

$$\begin{align}
f_{X\mid Y}(x,y) & = \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\displaystyle\int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x}
\end{align}$$

To complete just substitute $f_{X,Y}(x,y) \leftarrow e^{-y}$ and solve.